# Is dependabot.yml mandatory for GitHub Dependabot?

Tags: github, dependabot

Is adding of the `dependabot.yml` file mandatory for having GitHub Dependabot updates? Or is it just an additional option to change default values?

https://docs.github.com/en/github/administering-a-repository/configuration-options-for-dependency-updates

Comment: This. I would like to do some configuration, but I don't want to break what is working now. I want it to do what it is doing, but assign specific directories to specific teams. I guess I am out of luck because there's no doc on what the default configuration is.

Answer (score 9):

Technically `dependabot.yml` is not *required* - if you turn on dependabot from GitHub project settings / security, it'll start working. I turned on https://github.com/coreinfrastructure/best-practices-badge without a YAML file and it worked.

HOWEVER, it's not obvious to *others* that dependabot is being used if there's no `dependabot.yml` file, and that's a problem. For example, the [OpenSSF scorecard](https://github.com/ossf/scorecard) looks for the `dependabot.yml` file to determine if your project is using dependabot to keep things up to date. It's important to have your dependencies up-to-date, yes, but it's also important that your potential users *know* that you're keeping things up-to-date. So for full transparency it's better to have the configuration file posted within the source repo.

It'll also give you more control.

Answer (score 8):

The configuration file is necessary so that Dependabot knows which environments to update. This is a minimalist example from the [GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/keeping-your-actions-up-to-date-with-dependabot#enabling-dependabot-version-updates-for-actions) to update the dependencies of the GitHub Actions on a daily basis:

```yaml
version: 2
updates:

  - package-ecosystem: "github-actions"
    directory: "/"
    schedule:
      # Check for updates to GitHub Actions every weekday
      interval: "daily"
```

You can also see the necessary configurations in the [table of the GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/code-security/supply-chain-security/configuration-options-for-dependency-updates#configuration-options-for-updates).